# Why can't I use \@MakeShortVerb with minted?

Tags: verbatim, minted

`shortvrb`'s `\MakeShortVerb` allows defining single active tokens, e.g. `|`, in a way that makes `|\foo|` equivalent to `\verb|\foo|`. To do this, `|` is defined to expand to `\verb|` and added to both `\dospecials` and `\@sanitize`. Internally, `\MakeShortVerb\|` expands to `\def\@shortvrbdef{\verb}\@MakeShortVerb\|` and `\@shortvrbdef` is later used to set the expansion of `|`.

I want to use the same mechanism but with `minted`. In order to use the `minted` macro `\code` (as defined in the MWE below) insead of `\verb`, I defined

```latex
\def\MakeShortCode{\def\@shortvrbdef{\code}\@MakeShortVerb}
```

However, I get the error

```
! Paragraph ended before \minted@inline@ii was complete.
```

when using the shorthand. If I manually define

```latex
\def|{\code|}
```

the shorthand works fine. Inspection of the definition of `|` in both cases shows that they are indeed identical, so the only difference should be the registration of `|` in `\dospecials` and `\@sanitize`.

Why exactly does this error occur? How can I get around this without braking e.g. the `verbatim` environment? Is this a bug in `minted` or is there a good reason for this behavior?

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\newmintinline[code]{latex}{}

\makeatletter
  \def\MakeShortCode{\def\@shortvrbdef{\code}\@MakeShortVerb}
  \def\MakeShortLstinline{\def\@shortvrbdef{\lstinline}\@MakeShortVerb}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \NewDocumentCommand\decompose{ m }
    {
      {
        \ttfamily
        \tl_analysis_map_inline:Nn #1 
          {
            \exp_last_unbraced:No \token_to_str:N { ##1 }
            \ensuremath { \sb {##3} }
          }
      }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\catcode`\|=\active

\def|{\code|}
|\foo|

\decompose|

\MakeShortCode\|
%|\foo| % This will cause an error.

\decompose|

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why trying to overcomplicate things:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newmintinline[code]{latex}{}

\catcode`\|=\active
\makeatletter
\protected\def|{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\string|}{\code|}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

|\foo|

$|a+b|$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more complicated version that allows to locally remove a shorthand.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newmintinline[code]{latex}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makemintedshorthand}[1]{%
  \expandafter\chardef\csname catcode#1\endcsname=\catcode`#1
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup
    \protected\def~{%
      \ifmmode
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
      \else
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
      \fi
      {\code~}{#1}%
  }}%
  \catcode`#1=\active
}
\newcommand{\removemintedshorthand}[1]{%
  \ifcsname catcode\string#1\endcsname
    \catcode`#1=\csname catcode\string#1\endcsname
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\makemintedshorthand{|}

\begin{document}

|\foo|

$|a+b|$

\begingroup
\removemintedshorthand{|}
\code$abc|def$ \code|abc$def|

\verb|xyz| \verb"a|b"
\endgroup

|\foo|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Because then `|` will break `\verb` and `verbatim`. By proxy, this also breaks `minted`. Try `\code{The character | now breaks things.}` or just `\verb!|!`.

Comment: @schtandard That's the reason why such shorthands are not really recommended. On the other hand, if you do `\MakeShortVerb|`, you can't use `|` inside `|...|` can you?

Comment: Well, no, but you can still use it inside `\verb` and `verbatim`. (And one can define a second shorthand to use for these cases and reduce the situation one has to type `\verb` even further, which is what `l3doc` does. For me, it's okay to type `\verb` in those few cases, though.)

Comment: After thinking on it for a bit: Could you elaborate on why "such shorthands are not really recomended"? Are you saying that active characters in general are not recommended? If not, what makes using them for shorthands like this worse than other applications?

Comment: @schtandard Do you really think that `|\foo|` is clearer in the source than `\code|\foo|`?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant some technical reason. Well, in that example, no. I do think, however, that sentences with many small `\code` snippets can be uncluttered a bit and typed with more ease (`Use \code|a|, \code|b| or \code|c| as an option to \code|\foo|.` vs. `Use |a|, |b| or |c| as an option to |\foo|.`), much like how backticks for markup on this site are more convenient and easily read than `<code>` html tags. I can see that one might think otherwise, though.

Comment: @schtandard The question was bumped up, so I'll share some other bit of information. If you use *any* character as shorthand for verbatim (or minted), then you *can't* use it in the verbatim text. That's an obvious consequence of the rules. So your objections don't stand. However, I added code to (locally) remove a shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `\code|\foo|` is executed, TeX only scans for the second `|` after `\dospecials` changed its category code to `12`. `\@MakeShortVerb` defines `|`<sub>13</sub> to expand to `\code`<sub>0</sub>`|`<sub>13</sub> (the indices denote category codes), so `|\foo|` effectively expands to `\code`<sub>0</sub>`|`<sub>13</sub>`\foo`<sub>0</sub>`|`<sub>12</sub>, which can't work.

We can fix this by modifying `\MakeShortCode` to define `|`<sub>13</sub> as `\code`<sub>0</sub>`|`<sub>12</sub>.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\newmintinline[code]{latex}{}

\makeatletter
  \def\MakeShortCode{\def\@shortvrbdef{\code}\@MakeShortCode}
  \let\@MakeShortCode\@MakeShortVerb
  \patchcmd\@MakeShortCode
    {\expandafter\gdef\expandafter~\expandafter{\@shortvrbdef~}}
    {\xdef~{\expandafter\noexpand\@shortvrbdef\expandafter\@gobble\string#1}}
    {}{}
\makeatother

\MakeShortCode\|

\begin{document}\makeatletter

|\foo{bar} baz|

\begin{minted}{latex}
  I wrote |\foo{bar} baz|.
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```